# global function defining a $\mathcal{C}^1$ submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ submanifold of dimension $1$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then for each $x\in M$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $M\cap U=f^{-1}(\{0\})\cap U$ and $\nabla f\neq 0$ on $U$.

Question: Is it possible to just define $f$ globally such that $M=f^{-1}(\{0\})$?

Comment: Is $M$ compact? If not, there are counterexamples. See [Is every embedded submanifold globally a level set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23764/is-every-embedded-submanifold-globally-a-level-set).

Comment: @Behaviour,  no there are no counterexamples even in the non compact case because [such a global $f$ always exists](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879449/3217). See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/864058/3217).