# Can every smooth manifold be written as the intersection of smooth hypersurfaces?

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, implicit-function-theorem

If $\vec{f}\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^D, \mathbb{R}^K)$, $K=D-d$, such that the Jacobian, $D\vec{f}(\vec{x})$ of $\vec{f}$ has full-rank (i.e. $=K$) on $M=\vec{f}^{-1}(\vec{0})$, then $M$ is a smooth $d$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^D$. This is a consequence of the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

**Question:** What sort of smooth manifolds fail to have this representation and are there any classic references for such examples? In other words: are all smooth manifolds the intersection of smooth hypersurfaces?

My intuition tells me that self-intersections are problematic and also possibly orientation-issues. For example, and somewhat informally, consider a figure-eight closed curve in the plane with the point of self-intersection situated at the origin. There is not a unique tangent vector at this point, and thus the only vector that can be orthogonal to all such tangents is the zero vector-so that the gradient of any possible "implicit" function must vanish here--and so $f$ cannot satisfy the hypotheses above. Is this correct?

(I apologize if this is a little elementary--I am self studying differential geometry and it can be a little daunting to navigate the literature, especially with the variety of presentations between intrinsic, extrinsic, local coordinates, etc.)

**Edit/Update**
This nice summary answer on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37933/what-is-the-implicit-function-theorem-good-for/91422?_gl=1*1ob1upi*_ga*NTA0NjA5MTYyLjE2NTcxNTMzODQ.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4OTI5MTM0NS42MDUuMS4xNjg5MjkyMDYzLjAuMC4w#91422) gives a positive answer--locally--which I had expected knowing about the implicit function theorem. But all the classic examples I can think of, e.g. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ for the circle, $f(x,y,z) = \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2\right)+z^2-r^2$, the torus, are all defined globally. (For any of these, if you want to write the manifold in the form, say, $(x,y,F(x,y))$ you have to do this locally, of course.)

Let's consider the circle again. Locally, we know we can define the function $f_\alpha(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2}-y$ that has the equation $f_\alpha(x,y)=0$ defining a portion of the manifold. If we were ignorant and started with this, we could easily solve for $y$, and discover the global implicit equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$. I wonder if there are any conditions, and how deep they are, to ensure this is possible in general, if at all...

Comment: All smooth manifolds can be put in that form. That's [Whitney's embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem).

Comment: @NDB Sorry that I am being dense but you can you explain a little further. I get that we can map a $d$ dimensional smooth manifold smoothly into $2d$-Euclidean space by Whitney's but how can we construct/obtain $f$ so that $M = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2d}:f(x)=\vec{0}\}$ from this?

Comment: You can take $f(x)=\inf\{\|x-y\|^2\mid y\in M\}$.

Comment: @NDB But that $f$, as defined, is from $\mathbb{R}^{2d}\to \mathbb{R}$ which does not satisfy what I am looking for in the OP.

Comment: Which part it doesn't satisfy?

Comment: @NDB The codomain should be $\mathbb{R}^K$, $K=D-d$ (or if we use Whitney's, $K=2d-d=d$).

Comment: Ah, I see. You want them to be like [complete intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_intersection).

Comment: @NDB Yes, essentially the question can be rephrased as: can all smooth manifolds be written as the intersection of smooth hypersurfaces? I think I'll edit this into the OP.

Comment: Your manifold has to be stably parallelizable.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Oh, interesting! How much work is this "stably" qualifier doing?--because on, e.g., Wikipedia, it says that the ordinary $2$-sphere is *not* parallelizable, thanks to the Hairy ball theorem. But since $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ defines the sphere globally, I am guessing it is *stably* parallelizable--or did I severely misunderstand something? In any case, this is great motivation to get my hands dirty with tangent bundles etc-so thank you for the comment.

Comment: Google it. For instance, such manifolds are orientable. The question was definitely asked before.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810066/is-every-smooth-manifold-the-solution-set-of-finitely-many-equations/1810260#1810260

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Thanks! I found this and another linked last night--your answer is very instructive. I have marked this question as a duplicate now since I didn't get around to it last night.