# Submanifold that is not preimage

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-functions, submanifold

Does there exist an orientable manifold $M$ and a closed orientable submanifold $Z \subseteq M$ with codimension one so that $Z$ is not the preimage of a regular value of a smooth function $f:M\to N$?

Comment: Won't $Z$ have codimension $\dim N$?

Comment: Yes. I erased the requirement of codimension one.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Now the question has been answered, it is better not to change.

Comment: The general question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23764/is-every-embedded-submanifold-globally-a-level-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T$ be a tubular neighbourhood of $Z$ in $M$. The normal bundle of $Z$ in $M$ is an orientable line bundle and is therefore trivial. So there is a diffeomorphism $\phi : T \to Z\times(-\pi,\pi)$ such that $\phi(z) = (z, 0)$ for $z \in Z$. Now consider the map $f_0 : M \to S^1$ given by

$$f_0(m) = \begin{cases}
\exp(i\operatorname{pr}_2(\phi(m))) & m \in T\\
-1 & m \not\in T.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $f_0|_{\phi^{-1}(Z\times[-1,1])}$ is smooth, so we can deform to a smooth map $f: M \to S^1$ which agrees with $f_0$ on $\phi^{-1}(Z\times[-1,1])$. Now note that $1 \in S^1$ is a regular value of $f$ with $f^{-1}(1) = Z$.

More generally, if $Z$ is a codimension $k$ submanifold of $M$ with trivial normal bundle, then $Z$ is the preimage of a regular value of a map $f : M \to S^k$. This idea was developed by Thom and leads to the notion of Thom spaces and the Pontryagin-Thom construction.